# How to resolve window.location in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am passing php variables in the javascript window.location code the code is working properly but the problem is that the chrome or another browser blocked popups and the reports are not printing because of not allowing popups. I want to resolve this problem

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){ 
    $genid=$_POST['creategenReport'];
    $startdate=$_POST['sDate'];
    $enddate=$_POST['eDate'];
 echo '<script>window.open("reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'","_blank");</script>';
   }
  ?>
```

any idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Please add this after `"_blank",`

```
"resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=700, height=600, top=10, left=10"
```

As:

```
window.open("reportConsumption.php?creategenReport='.$genid.'&sDate='.$startdate.'&eDate='.$enddate.'","_blank","resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=700, height=600, top=10, left=10");
```

Comment: I have used _blank

Comment: i want to open as new tab not in a completely new window